# Hibernate 4 : saveOrUpdate exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate4, and Spring 3.

Hibernate is not updating instead it is always trying to insert.

My entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_SERVER")
public class ServerEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_item", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_item",sequenceName="SEQ_APP_SERVER")
    @Column(name="APP_SERVER_KEY")
    private int app_server_key;

    @Column(name="SYS_ID" , unique=true)
    private String sys_id;
    @Column(name="SERVER_NAME")
    private String server_name;
}
```

My Service class :

```
@Service("ServerService")
public class ServerServiceImpl implements ServerService{

// other code
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void addServer(ServerEntity server) {
    serverDao.addServer(server);

  }
}
```

Dao Class :

```
@Repository("ServerDao")
public class ServerDaoImpl implements ServerDao {
  @Override
  public void addServer(ServerEntity server) {
    try{
      this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(server);
      }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Other class :

```
ServerEntity serverEntity = new ServerEntity();
serverEntity.setSys_id((result.getSysId()));
serverEntity.setServer_name(result.getName());

ServerService serverService = (ServerService)        
applicationContext.getBean("ServerService");  
serverService.addServer(serverEntity);
```

Table :

```
  CREATE TABLE "APP_SERVER" 
   (           "APP_SERVER_KEY" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
                "CMDB_SYS_ID" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE ENABLE , 
                "SERVER_NAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("APP_SERVER_KEY") ENABLE
   ) ;
```

Exception coming :

```
05:36:40,292 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: insert into USER.APP_SERVER (SYS_ID,SERVER_NAME) values (?, ?)
05:36:40,558 INFO  [STDOUT] WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
05:36:40,558 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER.APP_SERVER_UK1) violated
05:36:40,684 INFO  [STDOUT] Exception occured... org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [OIMUSER.SPP_SERVER_UK1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Here why hibernate is inserting instead of updating. `sys_id` is already present in the database and here I want hibernate to update it as sys-id is already present.

What code change is required. Please suggest.

Comment: if there is any confusion in the question then plz let me know

Comment: What is the `OIMUSER.SPP_SERVER_UK1` constraint? Also why is your ID column String type? In your entity you have 3 fields, the "other class" that is doing the mapping does not specific the actual `int app_server_key;` ID which is the primary key in that case. That's why it's a new entity and will be inserted. You also need something like: `serverEntity.setApp_server_key((result.getApp_server_key()));`. Not to mention that your code style is bad and should make it cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @ Vaelyr : 1) app_server_key is the primary key which is generated by  @SequenceGenerator. 2) sys_id is varchar2 because it contains alpha numeric 3) SPP_SERVER_UK1 : At db side I have applied sys_id as unique constraint... I hope you understood.

Comment: Sequence or not, if you want to update, your entity needs to have a primary key set. In your case then you need to get the primary key value and set it to the entity you want to persist.

Comment: @Vaelyr : so means you are saying I need to make `serverEntity.setApp_server_key`. For insert : Which value I will set ? For Update : You are saying, first of all I need to fetch the row then then update

Comment: Why don't you use HibernateTemplate's saveOrUpdate() ?

Comment: I think you should read more about how Hibernate works, there is no point touching such framework without basic database knowledge. First you need to understand how do the mappings between java objects and database work. There are plenty of tutorials that explain it well. And yes, you need to set the id if you want to update, for inserting you don't need, because it's autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Student ss = new Student();
Student get = (Student) s.load(Student.class, new Long(id));
get.setDegree(newDegree);
tx.commit();
```

If your object is in persistent state then load your object's proxy & manipulate it. Once manipulation is done commit the transaction. Your object is automatically updated by hibernate.

**Have a look at** [Hibernate Load() Example](http://candidjava.com/hibernate-session-load-example-program-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably du to the miss of the correct equals function wich should be based on the ID of your entites, in other words Hibernate is not able to figure that is the same record